# jQuery Flex Select - How to set selected option?

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using the [flexselect](http://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/) plugin in my web app, and it works great, but now I need to change the selected option dynamically. In my case when another simple select changes, i need to set a different value of my flex select. I've try to use the function val() of jQuery, but it doesn't work.

```
$("#flex_select").flexselect();
$('#my_select').change(function(){
  if($(this).find(":selected").val() == 10){
    $('#flex_select').val( '1' );
  }
});
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use Event delegation to attach event. [Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('change','#my_select',function(){
   if($(this).find(":selected").val() == 10){
     $('#flex_select').val( '1' );
   }
 });
```